# Handling a periodic thread in MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a *.NET 4.0* _C# 4.0_ application. I am using *WPF* and the *Model-View-ViewModel* (MVVM) pattern.
I have my controls and everything is fine. The pattern is correctly applied and works fine thanks to view data-binding.

In particular, in my view, I have a data grid with some rows. The application needs to run a thread when this window is active and this thread needs, periodically, to access the grid's rows and perform some task with data collected from each row.

My problem is: where am I supposed to create an instance of the thread? In the View? in the ViewModel? In the Model?

I have a feeling that (in order to properly have data-binding), the thread should be handled in the context of the ViewModel. What is the best practice in this situation? Thankyou.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In particular, in my view, I have a data grid with some rows. The
>   application needs to run a thread when this window is active and this
>   thread needs, periodically, to access the grid's rows and perform some
>   task with data collected from each row.

I think your application doesn't need to access *the grid's rows*. Instead, it needs to access the *data that is bound to the grid's rows*.

You should then create your background worker (or thread) in your ViewModel, as you thread doesn't need to know anything about the View.